# Decode Firebase Dynamic Link back using JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-dynamic-links, capacitor

How can I convert a Firebase Short Dynamic Link (example.page.link/4eD2) back (example.com/test?var=1) with JS?

I see from here that you can create a Firebase dynamic link with REST... https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest

As far as I see, Firebase only has documentation for iOS, Android, Unity, and C++ libraries to listen for dynamic links. Is there a workaround or something that I can do with JS to convert it back with?

For more context (if it matters), I'm trying to use Ionic Capacitor's [App Plugin](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/app#method-addListener-1) to listen for the link click, but I'm only getting back the short decoded link.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?